# running eval code on a dataframe for each row in python as fast as possible

Tags: python, dataframe, eval

I have a dataframe where I have defined some set of rules to be applied for request data and return value for each rule. The rules which are to be applied are defined outside of the main processing function. The rules dataframe looks like this:

| rule_id | rule_name | rule_function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | frequency_check | frequency_check(request_data) |
| 2 | age_check | age_check(request_data) |

```
def process_rules(request_data, rules_df):
    rule_vals = []
    for i, row in rules_df.iterrows(): 
        rule_vals.append(eval(row['rule_function']))
    return rule_vals

def frequency_check(request_data):
    """ some code to return values"""

def age_check(request_data):
    """ some code to return values"""
```

The above approach is working but it is takinf ~1.1 second to evaluate and return the final result. Can anyone help me on the approach that will work fastest in this scenario.

Till now I have tried using dictionary comprehension instead of using rules_df and apply lambda function but none on them is giving significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to look at row - 1 (or row - *n* I suppose), then you are best avoiding operations on a row-by-row basis. Instead look at using pandas vectorised capabilities by operating on the entire column in one go.

See here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html